# Php combine variable and array value

Tags: php

I have an array. I want to generate dynamic variable with array values. When I run the code below, it doesn't work. I want to generate `$urlsHome` and `$urlsOffice`. How can I do?

```
$arr= ["Home", "Office"];

foreach ($arr as $key=>$type) {
    echo $urls.type;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I belive that's what you are looking for.

```
$arr = ["Home", "Office"];

foreach ($arr as $key=>$type) {
    ${'url' . $type} = $type;
    echo $urlHome;
}
```

This is the simple way to create dynamic variable in PHP.

Comment: @Matheusz  What is the name of the dynamic variable you have created?

Comment: @IWASBANNEDBYSOMESNOWFLAKE I printed it out, its concatenation of url and value of item in $arr. This is just example of how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You must use this fine { } brackets.

```
$urlsHome="this";
$urlsOffice="that";

$arr= ["Home", "Office"];

foreach ($arr as $key=>$type) {
    echo ${'urls'.$type}."<BR>";
}
```

results :

> this
>   that